# Inverting a Hierarchy with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Given the class

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
List<Article> articles;
```

How can I create a "map" from individual tags (that may be associated with 1 or more articles) with Linq?

```
Dictionary<string, List<Article>> articlesPerTag;
```

I know that I can select all of the tags like this

```
var allTags = articlesPerTag.SelectMany(a => a.Tags);
```

However, I'm not sure how to associate back from each selected tag to the article it originated from.

I know I can write this conventionally along the lines of

```
Dictionary<string, List<Article>> map = new Dictionary<string, List<Article>>();
foreach (var a in articles)
{
    foreach (var t in a.Tags)
    {
        List<Article> articlesForTag;
        bool found = map.TryGetValue(t, out articlesForTag);
        if (found)
            articlesForTag.Add(a);
        else
            map.Add(t, new List<Article>() { a });
    }
}
```

but I would like to understand how to accomplish this with Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specifically need it as a dictionary from tags to articles, you could use something like this.

```
var map = articles.SelectMany(a => a.Tags.Select(t => new { t, a }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.t, x => x.a)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Though it would be more efficient to use a lookup instead, it's precisely what you are trying to build up.

```
var lookup = articles.SelectMany(a => a.Tags.Select(t => new { t, a }))
    .ToLookup(x => x.t, x => x.a);
```

Comment: The missing piece in my mind was selecting `new {t, a}` instead of just `a.Tags`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One more way using GroupBy. A bit complicated though.

```
articles.SelectMany(article => article.Tags)
        .Distinct()
        .GroupBy(tag => tag, tag => articles.Where(a => a.Tags.Contains(tag)))
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                      group => group.ToList().Aggregate((x, y) => x.Concat(y).Distinct()));
```

Comment: That does not produce a `Dictionary<string, Article>`

Comment: Done. Now it should provide a Dictionary<string, List<Article>>.

Comment: I have simplified the query by having the result selection in ToDictionary() call.